What happens to initial conditions in a Linear System?
I have a basic question about LS:
What happens to an initial condition? For example, if $x(t)$ is transformed into $y(t)$ and that $x(t=0)=x_0$ how do we know the value of $y(t=0)$ ? I have seen a paragraph in A practical approach to signals and systems from D. Sundararajan that seems to be about it:

"The linearity condition implies that the total response of a linear
system is the sum of zero-input and zero-state components. The zero-input component
of the response of a system is its response due to the initial conditions alone with the
input assumed to be zero. The zero-state component of the response of a system is its
response due to the input alone with the initial conditions assumed to be zero. The
linearity of a system with respect to zero-input and zero-state responses should be
checked individually. In most cases, zero-state linearity implies zero-input linearity."

I have to say I hardly get anything about this exerpt*. But it seems to contain the answer to my above question about initial conditions?
*: I don't understand precisely what is $x$ look like in the zero-state case. Do they mean $x(t=0)=0$ and $x(t>0)$ equal to any function? In the zero-input case do they mean that $x(t>0)=0$ and $x(t=0)=x_0 \neq 0$ ?

We cannot necessarily infer anything about $y(t=0)$ from $x(t=0)$.
In very practical terms, imagine a very simple linear system: The "delay"; takes the input $x$, and delays it for $\tau$, and outputs it as $y$: $y(t) = x(t-\tau)$.
Now, knowing $x(t=0)$ suffices to know the output at $t=\tau$, but not at any earlier time.

But then how do we know that the image (by a TILS) of an exponential is an exponential? Exponential is (/can be) defined by the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and by the initial condition $f(0)=1$. The latter functional equation is verified by the image of an exponential by a TILS. But for the former, how do we know $y(0)=1$? We need it to achieve the proof that the image of an exponential by a TILS is an exponential.

I'm not convinced the image of an exponential is universally an exponential? Like, the trivial (output always 0) system is perfectly LTI, but its output is never an exponential.

I held as a truth that sinusoidal fidelity held for any TILS. And sinusoidal fidelity is based on the fact that the image by a TILS of a complex exponential is a complex exponential (with similar frequency). I know you're right but I can't see where my reasoning breaks down. Thanks for your answer.

with a complex exponential you mean a special case: the class of exponentials where the exponent is (purely) imaginary :) yep, these are eigenvectors of LTI systems, if you will. (the trivial system above just has one eigenvalue, 0)

Oh great! I am not sure I am able to see the exponentials as eigenvectors (because the convolution operator is too complicated for me). Yet I'd like to end the proof that the image of these complex exponentials are complex exponentials. I would need (to end my proof) to show that $y(0)=1$ where $y$ is the image of the complex exponential. But your answer above seems to say that no inference about $y(t=0)$ can be made, given the initial condition of $x$?
